# Where is media.repo file in RHEL 8.8 ootpa?

Tags: rhel

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.linuxtechi.com/setup-local-yum-dnf-repository-rhel-8/) to setup local yum repository in RHEL 8.8.

I've already  done these steps.

```
mount -o loop rhel-8.8-x86_64-boot.iso /opt
echo "/root/rhel-8.8-x86_64-boot.iso /opt iso9660 loop 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
mount -a
```

I tried to do this step:

```
[root@linuxtechi-rhel8 ~]# cp -v /opt/media.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/rhel8.repo
'/opt/media.repo' -> '/etc/yum.repos.d/rhel8.repo'
```

But it didn't work I tried to find `media.repo` using find command but it returned no results.

There is a file named `/etc/yum.repos.d/redhat.repo`

But that's the destination file in my case. I wonder what's the situation?

Comment: @dr_ check updated post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using boot ISO (`rhel-8.8-x86_64-boot.iso`) which doesn't have any packages on it so there isn't a repo file you could copy. If you want to follow the tutorial, you need to download the DVD ISO (`rhel-8.8-x86_64-dvd1.iso`).